# Google Script - Can't write to a single 2D array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I'm working with a 2D array in Google Script.  I have come across a problem I can't wrap my head around.  When I try to change a single array element in a 2D array, other values change as well...  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Here is a highly simplified example:

```
function arrayproblem() {
var arrayone = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
var bigarray = [];
bigarray.push(arrayone);
bigarray.push(arrayone);
bigarray.push(arrayone);
bigarray.push(arrayone);
bigarray.push(arrayone);
bigarray[3][3]="HELLO";
Logger.log(bigarray);
}
```

I'm clearly specifying that only element[3][3] be changed to "HELLO", but every [3]rd element in the array is changed.  The output is:

["A","B","C","HELLO","E"]

["A","B","C","HELLO","E"]

["A","B","C","HELLO","E"]

["A","B","C","HELLO","E"]

["A","B","C","HELLO","E"]

Why does it write "HELLO" to elements [0][3], [1][3], [2][3], [3][3], and [4][3]??

I'm trying to get this but can't:

["A","B","C","D","E"]

["A","B","C","D","E"]

["A","B","C","D","E"]

["A","B","C","HELLO","E"]

["A","B","C","D","E"]

Please help!  Many thanks.

Comment: And here is an even more brainstumping discovery.  The original 1D array called 'arrayone' is also showing ["A", "B", "C", "HELLO", "E"].  How is that possible?  There is nothing in the script that changes that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difference between the call by reference and the call by value. At the call by reference, it images that it shares variables. At the call by value, it images that it copies variables. At javascript, the object data type, which is array, slice, associative array and so on, and the primitive data type, which is number, string and bool, are the former and the latter, respectively.

Your script is the former.

For example, it shows simple sample of the call by reference.

```
var ar1 = [0,0,0,0,0];
var ar2 = ar1;
ar2[3] = 1;
Logger.log(ar1)
Logger.log(ar2)
```

In this case, both `ar1` and `ar2` become `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]`. Both `ar1` and `ar2` are changed by `ar2[3] = 1`. Because this is the call by reference.

In order to modify from the call by reference and the call by value, it copies `ar1` to `ar2` using [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) as follows. Using `concat()` is just one of samples. Of course, you can achieve the call by value like a proposal by @André.

```
var ar1 = [0,0,0,0,0];
var ar2 = ar1.concat();
ar2[3] = 1;
Logger.log(ar1)
Logger.log(ar2)
```

In this case, `ar1` and `ar2` are `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` and `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]`, respectively. `concat()` is a method to copy array.

Here, when it sees your script, `arrayone` is imported to `bigarray` using `push()`. This is the call by reference. So all elements in `bigarray` are changed by `bigarray[3][3]="HELLO"`.

When your script is modified to the call by value using `concat()`, it becomes as follows.

**Modified script :**

```
function arrayproblem() {
  var arrayone = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
  var bigarray = [];
  bigarray.push(arrayone.concat());
  bigarray.push(arrayone.concat());
  bigarray.push(arrayone.concat());
  bigarray.push(arrayone.concat());
  bigarray.push(arrayone.concat());
  bigarray[3][3]="HELLO";
  Logger.log(bigarray);
}
```

**Result :**

```
[
    [A, B, C, D, E],
    [A, B, C, D, E],
    [A, B, C, D, E],
    [A, B, C, HELLO, E],
    [A, B, C, D, E]
]
```

I think that this also becomes an answer for your comment. If this will be helpful for you, I'm glad.

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function arrayproblem() {
    var bigarray = [];
    bigarray.push(["A","B","C","D","E"]);
    bigarray.push(["A","B","C","D","E"]);
    bigarray.push(["A","B","C","D","E"]);
    bigarray.push(["A","B","C","D","E"]);
    bigarray.push(["A","B","C","D","E"]);
    bigarray[3][3]="HELLO";
    Logger.log(bigarray);
}
```

In your original code you are not pushing copies of arrayone into the bigarray, but the very same instance of arrayone many times. I mean, bigarray receives many references to the same object.